# How to create a node with custom nid in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm new to drupal 7 and for a project I need to create a node which starts with specific node id (or nid). I'm using php to create nodes. In localhost (using wamp for windows), I go to localhost/update.php for drupal to create the node. 
php code:

```
function myFunc_update_update_9003(&$sandbox) {
  $node = new stdClass();
     $node->type = 'page';
     node_object_prepare($node);
     $node->title    = "My Title";
     $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
     $node->uid = 1;
     $node->body[$node->language][0]['value']  = '';
     $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = text_summary('');
     $node->body[$node->language][0]['format']  = 'filtered_html';
     $node->path['pathauto'] = FALSE;
     $node->path = array('alias' => 'myPage/Page');
     if($node = node_submit($node)) {
         node_save($node);
     }
}
```

The plan is to group pages based on the page types. All static pages with information on, lets say android phones, should have the node id in 100s (nid = 100 to nid = 199) and all static pages with information on IOS phones, should have node id in 200s (nid = 200 to 299).
But, current nid in database is registered as 52 and I don't know how to start the new nodes from 100 or 200. Any help please?

Thank you.

Comment: The real question is "WHY?"..  nid is the primary key of most content in Drupal. It is not supposed to be use this way. What you want to achieve ( categorizing nodes ) could be done via Terms or a hundred other ways, but fix nid is probably the worst way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, this structure seems arbitrary and like it was not thoroughly planned out. Why not just create a field with a group ID or something using the normal drupal content types?

Comment: As I said, I'm new to drupal 7 and don't know how achieve it. Yes, categorizing the nodes is what I'm looking for. But, the thing is 3 people are working on same drupal server, one on each product and we need to categorize the nodes so that we dont step on each other. Hence, I thought nodes starting from 100 to 110 will be reserved to me and so on. Can I do that? Whats the alternative? Can you please tell me how to categorize nodes? Thank you.

Comment: you probably want different urls for each type of node. Take a look at the pathauto module